# Can PySpark Handle os.walk to Iterate Through Sub-Folders?

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I tested a couple samples of code that list all files in a specific folder (below).  However, neither one can handle iterating through sub-folders using a wildcard.

First Attempt:

```
import sys, os

root = "/dbfs/mnt/rawdata/2019/01/"+"01"+"/corp/"
path = os.path.join(root, "targetdirectory")
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(path, name))
```

Second Attempt:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/dbfs/mnt/rawdata/2019/01/01/corp/"):
    print(root)
    print(dirs)
    print(files)
```

So, in this example `/01/01/` represents January 1st (pretty obvious).  Is there some way to list all files in January all at once?  I'm working with Databricks and PySpark.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how pyspark factors into this, but os.walk will iterate through all subfolders of the root path. you're just using a subfolder of january as root, it will never 'break out' of the root path... try using "/dbfs/mnt/rawdata/2019/01/" as root if you want all january files

Comment: AHHH!! OF COURSE!!!

Comment: WHY Pyspark?? It's a simple Python task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sir
It does iterates...

```
import os
EXT = 'File_Name'
PATH = 'Path_Name'
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(PATH):
  for filename in files:
    filepath = subdir + os.sep + filename

    if filepath.endswith(EXT): 
        print (filepath)
```

please check the indentation